# Create a bubble/speech text style using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a client application, which has a chat interface. I am using a CustomHBox, with a  `SVGPath` and another `HBox` to create a speech box.

[image]

I add a drop-shadow effect, I can see the border of the `HBox`, which gives an effect that the triangle is not really a part of the speech text.

I wanted to know, if it possible to produce the same effect without using a `SVGPath`? It may include playing around the the `HBox` with the label.

The reason behind using `HBox` to as container and not a `Shape` using `Shape.union()` to create a `Triangle + Rectangle` is because once you have shape on the scene graph and not the rectangle, the `widthProperty.bind()` on the rectangle doesn't work.

Comment: Sir ltachiUchiha, check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642847/javafx-chat-bubble-perfection) maybe it might help, i even made a quick library out of it, idk if you still need it or maybe you could even make it better to fit your choice

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `-fx-shape` CSS attribute of JavaFX:

Let`s take this very (!) simple chat GUI:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    GridPane chat = new GridPane();
    chat.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    c1.setPercentWidth(100);
    chat.getColumnConstraints().add(c1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Label chatMessage = new Label("Hi " + i);
        chatMessage.getStyleClass().add("chat-bubble");
        GridPane.setHalignment(chatMessage, i % 2 == 0 ? HPos.LEFT
                : HPos.RIGHT);
        chat.addRow(i, chatMessage);
    }

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(chat);
    scroll.setFitToWidth(true);

    Scene scene = new Scene(scroll, 500, 500);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Test.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And we will use this [SVG Path from Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Speech_bubble.svg) in our css:

```
.chat-bubble {
    -fx-shape: "M 45.673,0 C 67.781,0 85.703,12.475 85.703,27.862 C 85.703,43.249 67.781,55.724 45.673,55.724 C 38.742,55.724 32.224,54.497 26.539,52.34 C 15.319,56.564 0,64.542 0,64.542 C 0,64.542 9.989,58.887 14.107,52.021 C 15.159,50.266 15.775,48.426 16.128,46.659 C 9.618,41.704 5.643,35.106 5.643,27.862 C 5.643,12.475 23.565,0 45.673,0 M 45.673,2.22 C 24.824,2.22 7.862,13.723 7.862,27.863 C 7.862,34.129 11.275,40.177 17.472,44.893 L 18.576,45.734 L 18.305,47.094 C 17.86,49.324 17.088,51.366 16.011,53.163 C 15.67,53.73 15.294,54.29 14.891,54.837 C 18.516,53.191 22.312,51.561 25.757,50.264 L 26.542,49.968 L 27.327,50.266 C 32.911,52.385 39.255,53.505 45.673,53.505 C 66.522,53.505 83.484,42.002 83.484,27.862 C 83.484,13.722 66.522,2.22 45.673,2.22 L 45.673,2.22 z ";
    -fx-background-color: black, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1;
    -fx-padding: 50;
}
```

Now we have a styled `Label` without any tricks. I admit, the used SVG Path is not ideal, but you can take whatever you want and fill it with colors etc..

Comment: Pretty Neat! Is there a way to keep the text always contained inside the shape I draw. [Please refer this image](http://i.imgur.com/1Ttuqe7.png?1). As you can see the text comes out of the `Shape`, we have drawn.

Comment: I think you have to increase the `-fx-padding`. The nearly circular shape of my sample SVG Path is not ideal for this, as `-fx-padding` is meant for square shapes..

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Did you had any success with these hints?